# Regex for a string of repeating characters and another optional one at the end

Tags: c#, regex

I can't find the right `Regex` code to match this:

- `tttttg` must be true
- `tg` must be true
- `tgg` must be false
- `tttgg` must be false
- `t` must be true
- `ttt` must be true
- `g` must be false
- `gggg` must be false

There can be any number of occurrences of `t` but at least one and it can optionally have only a `g` at the ending.
I tried `Match match = Regex.Match("ttgg", @"[t]+{g}|[t]+");` but it returns true, it must return false because there are 2 of `g` and there can only be one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that given the input string, `"ttgg"`, your pattern will happily match the *substring* `"ttg"`. Try putting start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around your pattern to prohibit extra leading or trailing characters. Other than that, you can significantly simply your pattern to this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("ttgg", @"^t+g?$")
```

This will match:

- the start of the string (`^`)
- one or more `t` characters
- an optional `g` character
- the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

The regex to use is: `"\bt\b|t+g\b|\bt+\b"`

`\bt\b` matches the lone t - word boundary, 't', word boundary.
`t+g\b` matches the remainder - one or more 't' and one and one only g.

I'm presuming your targets don't necessarily start at the beginning of the line.